# Beautiful Soup doesn't find element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A website I am trying to scrape has this html tag (I believe its an A/B test which is why I have two BS4 searches going at the same time).

`<h2 data-testid="price">39 777 kr</h2>`

I am trying to scrape the text inside this h2 tag, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried `find_all`, `select` and `find` but to no avail.

This is the full implementation:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
total_price = soup.body.find('span', attrs='u-t3')
total_price_alternative = soup.body.find('h2', attrs={'data-testid': 'price'})
if total_price is not None:
    main_price_info = {
      'title': 'Total price',
      'value': total_price.text.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')
    }
elif total_price_alternative is not None:
    main_price_info = {
      'title': 'Total price',
      'value': total_price_alternative.text.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')
    }
else:
    main_price_info = {
      'title': 'Total price',
      'value': 'Could not find price'
    }
```

URL to the site (It's in Norwegian): https://www.finn.no/car/used/ad.html?finnkode=297865903

Comment: What's the URL of the site?

Comment: Its in Norwegian, but here: https://www.finn.no/car/used/ad.html?finnkode=297865903

Comment: I have already made a lot of functions and logic revolving around beautiful soup. I can probably adapt my code but I would prefer not to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The price is stored inside `<script>` element, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use `json.loads` to parse this data:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.finn.no/car/used/ad.html?finnkode=297865903'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#horseshoe-config').text)

price = data['xandr']['feed']['pris']
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
39777
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to learn more about BS4 and how to work with the html/script data.

Comment: Andrej, thanks for this. I have worked with BS4 a few times and have simply given up on pulling data from scripts, but this actually helps me a lot too.